# Possible to use Azure Managed Identity to access Cosmos DB with Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, azure, entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb, azure-managed-identity

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use EF with a Cosmos DB and authenticate with Azure Managed Identity. I know you can add an interceptor for SQL databases to authenticate but I can't get it to work with Cosmos DB nor can I find any documentation on this.

Does that mean it's not possible?

Comment: we can use `system-assigned managed identities` to access Azure Cosmos DB data , Please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/managed-identity-based-authentication) Let us know if its helps.

Comment: How do see this being used with Entity Framework? Where you connect your context with `optionsBuilder.UseCosmos(connectionString)` and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Support is planned for EF Core 7.0 and tracked here: [Cosmos: Support AAD RBAC via the ClientSecretCredential](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26491)

> this is currently planned for the next release; that is EF Core 7.0, which will be released next November.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it to work with managed identity you can do a quick tweak (if you dont want to wait for EF 7 in november).
You can have a look at my gist what you need to do to create a custom extension and to get it to work.

https://gist.github.com/wkoeter/4ed90c7c8f61e3b3a52d2667d5a7c856

```
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCosmosCustom<CosmosContext>(
    endpoint: "https://westus22.documents.azure.com:443/",
    databaseName: "MyDb",
    managedIdentityClientId: "90df9398-990d-459f-8833-bfa4d762a4d7");

...
```

The github issue here
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26491